# Storing references between objects in database vs. in recommendation system?

Tags: database, machine-learning, database-design, artificial-intelligence

For a web app with a recommendation system powered by machine learning, we're pondering where to store references between objects; in our database tables or within our recommendation system (accessed via API)?

### A simplified case

The system works like this:

1. User selects one or more ingredients
2. Corresponding uid's for selected ingredients sent to recommendation API
3. API returns list of ingredient id's (the recommendations)
4. Data for list of ingredients retrieved from database (e.g. names, images etc.) and displayed on webpage

On that same webpage, for each ingredient listing, the following referenced information should show:

- category

*Note: This is an oversimplified example. In reality, we have to deal with hundreds of references like this*

---

**The conventional solution - To store references inside tables**

In this case the API simple returns a list of recommended ingredient id's:

```
{
    recommendations: [ingredient1, ingredient2 ...] 
}
```

These id's are used to retrieve ingredient info and category information (names, images etc...) from our database:

```
- ingredient
    - id
    - name
    - imageUrl
    - categoryId --> Reference to category table

- category
    - id
    - name
    - iconUrl
```

---

**The alternative solution - To store references inside recommendation system**

In this case, the API would sent back a list of ingredient objects **incl. references**:

```
{
    ingredientId1: {
        categoryReference: categoryId
        ...
    },
    ingredientId2: {
        categoryReference: categoryId
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So that the database can be kept simple without references:

```
- ingredient
    - id
    - name
    - imageUrl

- category
    - id
    - name
    - iconUrl
```

What we like about this "alternative" solution is that it makes changing references super easy. No hundreds of reference columns in database tables to maintain.

Super keen on hearing your thoughts based on your past experiences.

Thanks in advance